# Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am getting the below error while i was trigger build job in jenkins .there is no change from last build to this build but i am getting this error .
please help me

```
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ avsbe-web-ca ---
[INFO] Deleting /root/.jenkins/workspace/CA-16_PORTAL_BE-NG-WEB/16-PORTAL_BE/avsbe-web-ca/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ avsbe-web-ca ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ avsbe-web-ca ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 40 source files to /root/.jenkins/workspace/CA-16_PORTAL_BE-NG-WEB/16-PORTAL_BE/avsbe-web-ca/target/classes
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Try to run the maven with -X option  in order to get more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps to solve problem. Its work for me.

1. Uninstall you maven from running environment.
2. Install Maven form :

   wget http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.3.9/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz
3. Extract tar file using:

   tar -zxvf apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz
4. Now set M2_HOME in environment. Open  `vi /etc/profile`
5. End of file add below lines and save file.

   export M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/

   export M2="$M2_HOME"bin

   export PATH=$PATH:$M2
6. Compile this file using `source /etc/profile` command.
7. Your Maven home path is set. Yo can check using `echo $M2_HOME` command.
8. Not set /opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/ as a Maven path on jenkins.
9. Run your project from jenkis.